# Не получается эту часть блока адаптировать. В чем проблема?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивность

Надеюсь тут найду ответ на свой вопрос.
Не могу понять почему paddingами не смещается повыше. Конечно, тут я нашел что сам блок имеет вот такой размер, но как тогда исправить? Если десктоп потом меняется если поменять paddingи там.[image: Первый блок][image: Из десктопа][image: Второй блок] p.s Добавил код[image: +первый][image: +второй][image: весь контейнер и картинки]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 6fr 1fr;
  }
.music-2 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr }
  .pt {
    height: 50vh
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-size: cover
    background-position:  center
    color: white }
  .rak1 {
    background-image: url("../img/CONTAINER4.png")
    padding: 140px 0px 0px 220px }
    .s1 {
      font-family: FiraSans2
      font-size: 20px
      padding-left: 3px }
    .s2 {
      font-size: 34px
      padding-top: 25px
      padding-right: 50px
      font-weight: bold
      line-height: 40px }
    .s-button {
      padding-top: 50px
      padding-left: 15px }
      a {
        text-decoration: none
        color: white
        border: 2px solid white
        border-radius: 50px
        padding: 13px 17px 13px 17px
        letter-spacing: 3px
        font-family: FiraSans2 }
  .rak2 {
    background-image: url("../img/CONTAINER3.png")
    padding: 140px 0px 0px 60px }
    .i1 {
      font-family: FiraSans2
      font-size: 20px
      padding-left: 3px }
    .i2 {
      font-size: 34px
      padding-top: 25px
      padding-right: 200px
      font-weight: bold
      line-height: 40px }
    .i-button {
      padding-top: 50px
      padding-left: 10px }
      a {
        text-decoration: none
        color: white
        border: 2px solid white
        border-radius: 50px
        padding: 13px 17px 13px 17px
        letter-spacing: 3px
        font-family: FiraSans2 }
        
+media-breakpoint-up(xl)

.main-text-header  {
  padding-top: 100px }
.about-right {
  padding-top: 20px
  padding-bottom: 20px }
.v-button {
  padding-bottom: 60px
  display: flex }
.music-1 {
  height: 100% }
  .music1 {
    height: 100% }
  .about-music {
    width: 370px }
```

```html
<section class="music-2 grid">

 <div class="rak1 pt">
  <div class="s1">SPOTIFY</div>
  <div class="s2">Follow me, stream and add<br>
   my songs to your Spotify playlist.</div>
  <div class="s-button"><a href="#">FOLLOW ON SPOTIFY</a></div>
 </div>
 <div class="rak2 pt">
  <div class="i1">ITUNES</div>
  <div class="i2">Buy and download my songs
   from iTunes.</div>
  <div class="i-button"><a href="#">BUY FROM ITUNES</a></div>
 </div>
 
</section>
```

Comment: я хочу нажать на кнопку `Выполнить код` и посмотреть результат...организуйте пожалуйста минимум...и вам обязательно помогут. Как вы предлагаете смотреть к чему применяются ваши css классы? юзать на имейджу постоянно и обратно?

Comment: сделал. но изображения не видит

Comment: почему у вас стили так "криво" записаны? где {}? фигурныес кобки (тело)... как у вас стили работают вообще?

Comment: это на предпроцессоре saas...сейчас исправлю